# Using XML as storage and Google Drive

Tags: c#, xml, google-drive-api

As an inexpert programmer, I'm planning to develop a simple single-user C# Windows Forms application for a doctor's office. The doctor wants to store, read and modify simple data about patients (personal data and medical history). It's just Strings, integers and dates. 1000-5000 patients.
He would like to access the data only from 2 different personal computers and never simultaneously. He doesn't have in principle any hardware but these 2 laptops.

Well, what I thought is to use XML files as storage files (with all patients' data) and store this files in the Google Drive app folder of his laptops to achieve the disponibility in the two locations. I thought this because it's really simple, but I've never been taught something similar...

so... you think it could work or it's just a big stupidity? and if so, what do you suggest?

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a server less database like [SQL Server Compact](https://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx) or [SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). They would be better than XML files in every sense and the DB file can be in google drive. But as the file grows bigger uploads and downloads will be an issue. Ensuring that only one instance of your application is using that DB is also important.

You can also use a cloud solution like SQL Azure and [Microsoft Sync framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx) for more robust solution which would be suitable.

Comment: Thanks @Pratik, I'm new in these serverless DBs... there are so many things I'm not aware of!! I'll take a look at that since it sounds good for this situation...

Comment: I've been taking a look and this serverless DBs is exactly what I wanted, 'cause you have all your DB in a single file... it's perfect! but what about the thing of putting this file in Google Drive? do you think is a good solution? it's easy and it's free, you don't need even to use any API because GoogleDrive creates a folder in your user folder...

Comment: I cannot really say how good it would work. If the DB file changes as your application runs I would expect google drive to start a sync upload. I would expect this to be a full upload rather than some differential upload and this could be a performance/bandwidth killer especially as the DB file continues to grow in size. You can try things like making a temporary copy of the DB file to a temp folder at application startup, work from there and then on application shutdown move it back to the google drive for sync. But I really don't think this is a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

First review the HIPAA security rule. If the doctor's office is a covered entity there are a lot of pitfalls to protecting patient data (and financial liability).

http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/administrative/securityrule/index.html

Since you're dealing with PII that is covered by breach notification laws in 47 states - that's a whole different level of headache. Can it be stored in XML? Sure, just ensure everything is strongly encrypted in transit and at rest. Is it a good idea? Probably not.  Since breaches are strict liability statutes in certain data types, it's a good idea to do it right.

To get a cursory idea of the concerns look at the Microsoft Healthvault or archived Google Health HIPAA overview. The ARRA extensions to the act have made it more complicated. In short though.

HIPAA requires that health care providers and other services maintain a minimum standard of "reasonable and appropriate safeguards to prevent intentional or unintentional use or disclosure of health information".

As a side note, you could just as easily store the data in a SQL server compact database file or Access database file, which can at least provide some native protections for the data.

Comment: Thanks @iivel. I've not even considered those issues and neither have the doctor (who is my father btw :)) The office is in Spain, but I guess we have similar laws... I don't really know anything about legal issues... do you think that if everything is just strongly encrypted, it would be acceptable in legal terms?

Comment: I do know that EU privacy laws are much stricter. Strong encryption is a start, and if anyone other than your father requires access there will be a lot more to deal with. As it stands, I'd recommend a localized DB that you can attach to. Encrypt and password protect the DB file & also encrypt sensitive data. Specifics for your situation would be under the DPR: http://ec.europa.eu/justice/data-protection/index_en.htm

Answer (score 0):

XML (and JSON) should be used for transmitting information (eg: responses to Ajax queries), not as databases.  It's tempting to treat XML as a database sometimes because of its querying, but resist the temptation!  Performance, scalability and future support could be issues.